# Is MRV of use without FC?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am studying CSP in AI subjects. I am a bit confused. What happens if we use MRV without methods like FC? Is it still useful?
Maybe this question is very stupid! But I do not have experience in working with CSP stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum remaining value(MRV) is general trick(precautionary measure I'd say) to perform forward chaining efficiently. One is free to do chaining using any variable but may not foresee failure earlier and will have to back track after wasting lot of time.